I Do I Retrieve The Value Of A Chatbubble MessageBar Widget
I am using the Chat Bubble flutter package to build a message App. I am finding it difficult to retrieve the user input of the message sent. In a Textfield widget, we use the Controller to retrieve the inputs made by a user. How do I get the input made on a Bubble MessageBar. Here is my code:
 MessageBar(
  onSend: (_) => print('Message sent'),
  actions: [
    InkWell(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 24,
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.camera_alt,
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 24,
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
),


onSend: (msg) => print('Message sent: $msg')

Thanks it works. How can I mark this as the answer?

As @psking has pointed out in the comment section, you can specify a name for your parameter and then refer to it by name, like
 MessageBar(
  onSend: (msg) => print('Message sent: $msg'),
  actions: [
    InkWell(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 24,
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.camera_alt,
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 24,
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
),


